# Can't get my Player Movement script to work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and I followed a tutorial and did everything correctly no errors in the code but my player just wouldn't move when I pressed the arrow keys (or any other button).

Here's my code:

```
    public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D body;

    private void Awake() {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }


    private void Update() {
        Vector2 vector2 = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), body.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any help thanks.

Comment: Can you show us your inspector of your object please?

Comment: You are only setting a local variable. I don't know Unity, but wouldn't you have to update a property of the body to make a difference? E.g.? `body.velocity = vector2;`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I fixed that up but the problem is still happening.

Answer (score 1):

In your Update method, you are creating a new Vector2 in which the x component is the current value of your horizontal input and the y component is the current velocity of your Rigidbody2D on the y axis.  However, you are not doing anything with that Vector2 that you create.

As a starting point change the Update method as follows:

```
private void Update() {
    float xMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    body.AddForce(new Vector2(xMovement * 5f, 0f), ForceMode.Force);
}
```

That should at least get your character moving.  You will need to do a lot more work to get it moving in the way that you want. The above code is literally just to get you started.

AddForce, as the name suggests, applies a force to your Rigidbody2D.  This force is applied with respect to the forces that are already applied to it (e.g gravity).  Consequently, you do not need to include the Rigidbody's current velocity vector.  If you apply force against its current velocity vector, it will slow down.  If you apply it with the current velocity vector, it will speed up.

**Note:** I have told you to AddForce in the Update method but you should NEVER do that in your final code.  Applying forces to physics objects should always be done in FixedUpdate.  However, that is beyond the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
    public class movement2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D body;

    float horizontal;
    float vertical;

    public float runSpeed = 10.0f;
    
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * runSpeed, vertical * runSpeed);   
    }
}
```